# How to use CIContext drawImage:inRect:fromRect: with a CADisplayLink

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-image

[From the docs on `CIContext drawImage:inRect:fromRect:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIContext_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CIContext/drawImage%3ainRect%3afromRect%3a):

> .. On iOS 6, this method is asynchronous ..

So if I am using it in a [CADisplayLink](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) it runs into a problem since it will keep firing off asynchronous draws at 60fps while the actual drawing might not be able to keep up.

```
- (void) displayLinkDidFire:(CADisplayLink *)displatLink;
{
    CFTimeInterval duration = [displatLink duration];
    CGFloat fps = round (1.0 / duration);
    NSLog(@"%f fps", fps); // Always logs 60 fps since drawImage is async

    // This method is fast since a CIImage is just a 'recipe' for an image
    CIImage * result = [Helper generateCIImage];

    // This drawing is unable to keep up with the calls to the displayLinkDidFire method
    [self.ciContext drawImage:result
                       inRect:self.destFrame
                     fromRect:self.targetFrame];
}
```

How do I get around this issue?

---

**Edit - more info**

I am using CoreImage with an `EAGLContext` (for better drawing performance according to WWDCs).

```
self.eaglContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

self.ciContext = [CIContext
                  contextWithEAGLContext:self.eaglContext
                  options: @{kCIContextWorkingColorSpace:[NSNull null]} ];

GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
view.context = self.eaglContext;
view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;

NSURL * testImageURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"image" withExtension:@"jpg"];
NSAssert(nil != testImageURL, @"Image not found");

self.image = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:testImageURL
                                     options:@{ kCIImageColorSpace:[NSNull null] }];

[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.eaglContext];

self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(displayLinkDidFire:)];

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Comment: Generally a display link will do what it needs and then call `setNeedsDisplay` to tell the view to refresh. This doesn't result in any asynchronous timing issues.

Comment: @Rob I don't think that the display link invokes `-setNeedsDisplay`. It works independently of the standard `-drawRect:` view update cycle.

Comment: @Rob - Thanks for your comment.  I am getting about 0.5 visible fps on my device whereas the displayLink was firing at 60 fps, so I assumed the async was the issue.  Are you saying that it should not matter that drawImage is async or that I should be using something other than `CADisplayLink` to trigger drawing?

Comment: @Robert You either need to speed up your drawing, lower your refresh rate to suit your drawing speed, or you need to skip frames. If it takes 2 seconds to draw your image, CADisplayLink is not much use to you. You might as well use a while() loop. Based on your updates, I recommend loading a proper OpenGL texture with your image data before you start rendering. Loading from a file into memory, then copying to the frame buffer is probably just too slow.

Comment: @BoredAstronaut agreed, it doesn't call `setNeedsDisplay` automatically, but when doing your own animation, it's a common technique to have the `CADisplayLink` handler call `setNeedsDisplay`. And the frequency of the display link calls will automatically match the animation's FPS.

Comment: @BoredAstronaut - That sounds perfect - can point me out how to loading a proper OpenGL texture? - perhaps as an answer - then I can up-vote it :) I haven't used OpenGL much... Also are you saying that I should roll my own Display timer?  I was thinking about this but I was not sure how to get a notification when the drawing is complete?

Comment: @Rob - Yes this is exactly what I am after - having the frequency match the FPS. If I was to roll my own timer / loop I would not know when the draw cycle is complete so that I can trigger the next call cycle.  Do you have any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: I am thinking that I perhaps need to call GLFinish to block the thread until drawing is complete?  http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glFinish

Comment: @Both - The solution was to use a OpenGL ES rendering loop instead, see below.

Comment: Uploading a texture involves a bunch of steps. Moreover, it has to be rendered on geometry (usually a quad made of two rectangles). But if you're changing the image every frame, which I forgot to ask about, I don't know if it would be faster. On the other hand, it's possible to render HD video at 30fps on modern iOS hardware, so there must be some serious performance drags in your CIImage (something I couldn't help with). There are too many variables that affect rendering performance with copying an image to the display to address them all here.

Comment: @BoredAstronaut - The output image is changed on every frame, but the input/source image is always the same - it sounds to me like a texture is a good idea no?  The rendering is at 30 fps now (see answer below) I believe the issue was that a new frame was kicked off before the last one was rendered so it kept cancelling frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutuion was to use an "OpenGL ES rendering loop " instead of trying to build one with `CADisplayLink`.  Luckily this was easy since a [`GLKViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKViewController_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) does this automtically:

> The GLKViewController class provides all of the standard view controller functionality, but additionally implements an OpenGL ES rendering loop.

The only down side is that this strongly ties you to using a `GLKViewController` instead of a just adding a `GLKView` to an existing UIView.  To get around this you need to work out how to implement your own OpenGL ES rendering loop.

```
// The GLKViewController automatically calls this method
- (void) updateScreen
{        
    CIImage * result = [Helper generateCoreImage];

    // Clears the screen to a grey color 
    glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    [self.ciContext drawImage:result
                       inRect:self.destFrame
                     fromRect:self.targetFrame];

    // `display` needs to be called here according to the docs.
    GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
    [view display];
}
```